# Visual Studio 2010 C++ /w Google Protocol Buffers. Cannot find 60 externals. Cannot compile

Tags: c++

I followed the instructions to the best of my ability. downloaded GPBuffers 5.0rc1  put the src/google folder into my project directory.  Added the path to Settings > C/C++ > "Additional Include Directories".

But I think I need to place a -lprotobuf compiler option somewhere. I tried adding this to the C/C++ and Linker in the Settings > xxx > Additional Command Line Parameters.

But no luck.

It seems the libprotobuf.lib, libprotobuf-lite.lib and libprotoc.lib are missing.  Perhaps it did not build correctly..

I have my serverThread.cpp which looks like:

```
#include "serverThread.h"
#include "sendStruct.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "messages.pb.h"
```

The log is reproduced below.

It seems its missing a reference to some library.  As most of the dependencies are there.

```
Error   62  error LNK1120: 60 unresolved externals  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\Debug\ServerUpdater.exe
Error   37  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString" (?kEmptyString@internal@protobuf@google@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@B)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   34  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::SetCachedSize(int)const " (?SetCachedSize@Message@protobuf@google@@EBEXH@Z)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   27  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::IsInitialized(void)const " (?IsInitialized@Message@protobuf@google@@UBE_NXZ)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   28  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::MergePartialFromCodedStream(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *)" (?MergePartialFromCodedStream@Message@protobuf@google@@UAE_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@23@@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName(void)const " (?GetTypeName@Message@protobuf@google@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   22  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString(void)const " (?InitializationErrorString@Message@protobuf@google@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   35  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall google::protobuf::MessageLite::InitializationErrorString(void)const " (?InitializationErrorString@MessageLite@protobuf@google@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   29  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::ByteSize(void)const " (?ByteSize@Message@protobuf@google@@UBEHXZ)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsed(void)const " (?SpaceUsed@Message@protobuf@google@@UBEHXZ)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   31  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray@MessageLite@protobuf@google@@UBEPAEPAE@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(class google::protobuf::MessageLite const &)" (?CheckTypeAndMergeFrom@Message@protobuf@google@@UAEXABVMessageLite@23@@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   26  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::Clear(void)" (?Clear@Message@protobuf@google@@UAEXXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   32  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::CopyFrom(class google::protobuf::Message const &)" (?CopyFrom@Message@protobuf@google@@UAEXABV123@@Z) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   24  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields(void)" (?DiscardUnknownFields@Message@protobuf@google@@UAEXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::MergeFrom(class google::protobuf::Message const &)" (?MergeFrom@Message@protobuf@google@@UAEXABV123@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   30  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::SerializeWithCachedSizes(class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizes@Message@protobuf@google@@UBEXPAVCodedOutputStream@io@23@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   43  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadVarint32Fallback(unsigned int *)" (?ReadVarint32Fallback@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@AAE_NPAI@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadVarint32(unsigned int *)" (?ReadVarint32@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@QAE_NPAI@Z) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   53  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static int __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32Fallback(unsigned int)" (?VarintSize32Fallback@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@CAHI@Z) referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32(unsigned int)" (?VarintSize32@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@SAHI@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   49  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32FallbackToArray(unsigned int,unsigned char *)" (?WriteVarint32FallbackToArray@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@CAPAEIPAE@Z) referenced in function "public: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteTagToArray(unsigned int,unsigned char *)" (?WriteTagToArray@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@SAPAEIPAE@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   44  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringFallback(char const *,int,enum google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation)" (?VerifyUTF8StringFallback@WireFormat@internal@protobuf@google@@CAXPBDHW4Operation@1234@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8String(char const *,int,enum google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation)" (?VerifyUTF8String@WireFormat@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXPBDHW4Operation@1234@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   42  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: unsigned int __thiscall google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadTagFallback(void)" (?ReadTagFallback@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@AAEIXZ) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::ReadTag(void)" (?ReadTag@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@QAEIXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   38  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::ClearFallback(void)" (?ClearFallback@UnknownFieldSet@protobuf@google@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::Clear(void)" (?Clear@UnknownFieldSet@protobuf@google@@QAEXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   61  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::Reserve(int)" (?Reserve@RepeatedPtrFieldBase@internal@protobuf@google@@IAEXH@Z) referenced in function "protected: class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber * __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::Add<class google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber>::TypeHandler>(void)" (??$Add@VTypeHandler@?$RepeatedPtrField@VPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@@protobuf@google@@@RepeatedPtrFieldBase@internal@protobuf@google@@IAEPAVPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@XZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   58  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase::Swap(class google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrFieldBase *)" (?Swap@RepeatedPtrFieldBase@internal@protobuf@google@@IAEXPAV1234@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber>::Swap(class google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber> *)" (?Swap@?$RepeatedPtrField@VPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@@protobuf@google@@QAEXPAV123@@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::GeneratedMessageReflection::GeneratedMessageReflection(class google::protobuf::Descriptor const *,class google::protobuf::Message const *,int const * const,int,int,int,class google::protobuf::DescriptorPool const *,class google::protobuf::MessageFactory *,int)" (??0GeneratedMessageReflection@internal@protobuf@google@@QAE@PBVDescriptor@23@PBVMessage@23@QBHHHHPBVDescriptorPool@23@PAVMessageFactory@23@H@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::~LogMessage(void)" (??1LogMessage@internal@protobuf@google@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::LogMessage(enum google::protobuf::LogLevel,char const *,int)" (??0LogMessage@internal@protobuf@google@@QAE@W4LogLevel@23@PBDH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::~UnknownFieldSet(void)" (??1UnknownFieldSet@protobuf@google@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@QAE@XZ$0   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::UnknownFieldSet(void)" (??0UnknownFieldSet@protobuf@google@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::Person_PhoneNumber(void)" (??0Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@QAE@XZ)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class google::protobuf::FileDescriptor const * __thiscall google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?FindFileByName@DescriptorPool@protobuf@google@@QBEPBVFileDescriptor@23@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage & __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage::operator<<(char const *)" (??6LogMessage@internal@protobuf@google@@QAEAAV0123@PBD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   60  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::PushLimit(int)" (?PushLimit@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@QAEHH@Z) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadMessageNoVirtual<class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber>(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*,class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber *)" (??$ReadMessageNoVirtual@VPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SA_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@23@PAVPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   39  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SkipField(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *,unsigned int,class google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet *)" (?SkipField@WireFormat@internal@protobuf@google@@SA_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@34@IPAVUnknownFieldSet@34@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::MergePartialFromCodedStream(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *)" (?MergePartialFromCodedStream@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UAE_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   41  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadString(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (?ReadString@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SA_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@34@PAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::MergePartialFromCodedStream(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *)" (?MergePartialFromCodedStream@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UAE_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class google::protobuf::DescriptorPool const * __cdecl google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool(void)" (?generated_pool@DescriptorPool@protobuf@google@@SAPBV123@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class google::protobuf::MessageFactory * __cdecl google::protobuf::MessageFactory::generated_factory(void)" (?generated_factory@MessageFactory@protobuf@google@@SAPAV123@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   52  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::ComputeUnknownFieldsSize(class google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const &)" (?ComputeUnknownFieldsSize@WireFormat@internal@protobuf@google@@SAHABVUnknownFieldSet@34@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::ByteSize(void)const " (?ByteSize@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UBEHXZ)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   48  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SerializeUnknownFieldsToArray(class google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const &,unsigned char *)" (?SerializeUnknownFieldsToArray@WireFormat@internal@protobuf@google@@SAPAEABVUnknownFieldSet@34@PAE@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray(unsigned char *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizesToArray@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UBEPAEPAE@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   51  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteRawToArray(void const *,int,unsigned char *)" (?WriteRawToArray@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@SAPAEPBXHPAE@Z) referenced in function "public: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringToArray(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned char *)" (?WriteStringToArray@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@SAPAEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAE@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   50  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint64ToArray(unsigned __int64,unsigned char *)" (?WriteVarint64ToArray@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@SAPAE_KPAE@Z) referenced in function "public: static unsigned char * __cdecl google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32SignExtendedToArray(int,unsigned char *)" (?WriteVarint32SignExtendedToArray@CodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@SAPAEHPAE@Z)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const *,int)" (?InternalAddGeneratedFile@DescriptorPool@protobuf@google@@SAXPBXH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   54  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Merge(class google::protobuf::Message const &,class google::protobuf::Message *)" (?Merge@ReflectionOps@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXABVMessage@34@PAV534@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::MergeFrom(class google::protobuf::Message const &)" (?MergeFrom@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UAEXABVMessage@protobuf@google@@@Z)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   45  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::SerializeUnknownFields(class google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const &,class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)" (?SerializeUnknownFields@WireFormat@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXABVUnknownFieldSet@34@PAVCodedOutputStream@io@34@@Z) referenced in function "public:virtual void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::SerializeWithCachedSizes(class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizes@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UBEXPAVCodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   46  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteEnum(int,int,class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)" (?WriteEnum@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXHHPAVCodedOutputStream@io@34@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::SerializeWithCachedSizes(class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizes@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UBEXPAVCodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   57  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteInt32(int,int,class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)" (?WriteInt32@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXHHPAVCodedOutputStream@io@34@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person::SerializeWithCachedSizes(class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizes@Person@ArchProtocol@@UBEXPAVCodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   56  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteMessageMaybeToArray(int,class google::protobuf::MessageLite const &,class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)" (?WriteMessageMaybeToArray@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXHABVMessageLite@34@PAVCodedOutputStream@io@34@@Z) referenced in function"public: virtual void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person::SerializeWithCachedSizes(class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizes@Person@ArchProtocol@@UBEXPAVCodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   47  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)" (?WriteString@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXHABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAVCodedOutputStream@io@34@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::SerializeWithCachedSizes(class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream *)const " (?SerializeWithCachedSizes@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UBEXPAVCodedOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const *,void (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &))" (?InternalRegisterGeneratedFile@MessageFactory@protobuf@google@@SAXPBDP6AXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedMessage(class google::protobuf::Descriptor const *,class google::protobuf::Message const *)" (?InternalRegisterGeneratedMessage@MessageFactory@protobuf@google@@SAXPBVDescriptor@23@PBVMessage@23@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::`anonymous namespace'::protobuf_RegisterTypes(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?protobuf_RegisterTypes@?A0x2751caee@ArchProtocol@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall google::protobuf::Closure::~Closure(void)" (??1Closure@protobuf@google@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall google::protobuf::Closure::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GClosure@protobuf@google@@UAEPAXI@Z) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::FunctionClosure0::~FunctionClosure0(void)" (??1FunctionClosure0@internal@protobuf@google@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(int *,void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?GoogleOnceInit@protobuf@google@@YAXPAHP6AXXZ@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::~Message(void)" (??1Message@protobuf@google@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@QAE@XZ$0   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall google::protobuf::MessageLite::~MessageLite(void)" (??1MessageLite@protobuf@google@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall google::protobuf::MessageLite::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GMessageLite@protobuf@google@@UAEPAXI@Z) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(class google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage &)" (??4LogFinisher@internal@protobuf@google@@QAEXAAVLogMessage@123@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AssignDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   59  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::PopLimit(int)" (?PopLimit@CodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "public: static bool __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadMessageNoVirtual<class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber>(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *,class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber *)" (??$ReadMessageNoVirtual@VPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@@WireFormatLite@internal@protobuf@google@@SA_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@23@PAVPerson_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@@Z)    C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   40  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::AddVarint(int,unsigned __int64)" (?AddVarint@UnknownFieldSet@protobuf@google@@QAEXH_K@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::MergePartialFromCodedStream(class google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream *)" (?MergePartialFromCodedStream@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@UAE_NPAVCodedInputStream@io@protobuf@google@@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   55  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet::MergeFrom(class google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet const &)" (?MergeFrom@UnknownFieldSet@protobuf@google@@QAEXABV123@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber::MergeFrom(class ArchProtocol::Person_PhoneNumber const &)" (?MergeFrom@Person_PhoneNumber@ArchProtocol@@QAEXABV12@@Z)   C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInitImpl(int *,class google::protobuf::Closure *)" (?GoogleOnceInitImpl@protobuf@google@@YAXPAHPAVClosure@12@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(int *,void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?GoogleOnceInit@protobuf@google@@YAXPAHP6AXXZ@Z)  C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::OnShutdown(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?OnShutdown@internal@protobuf@google@@YAXP6AXXZ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::VerifyVersion(int,int,char const *)" (?VerifyVersion@internal@protobuf@google@@YAXHHPBD@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ArchProtocol::protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto(void)" (?protobuf_AddDesc_messages_2eproto@ArchProtocol@@YAXXZ) C:\work\freetimeC+\ServerUpdater\ServerUpdater\messages.pb.obj
```

Comment: The Microsoft Incremental Linker (`LINK.EXE`) doesn't understand `-lprotobuf`, which sounds like a `ld` option.

Comment: You probably need to build the google protocol library yourself to use under Visual Studio. And to me that would not have anything to do with placing files into an application you created. If there is not a supplied visual studio project however you may need to create one for the library and include all the source files and headers.

Comment: Beat me to it.  Got it worked.  I used the MinGW documented way to compile it and I guess it failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Needed to compile Protobuf correctly. There is a vsprojects folder.  Just build ONLY the libprotobuf and add the libprotobuf.lib as reference to the project by going to:

Properties > Linker > Input :  Additional Dependencies > Edit...

If you copied it to your project folder/google  put in google/libprotobuf.lib

Everything should compile smoothly now.

Comment: Where is the vsprojects folder? just found CMake

Comment: @Beachwalker You have to create the solution using cmake, follow the cmake/readme.md

Answer (score 6):

If you are building protobufs as a DLL then you will also need to define `PROTOBUF_USE_DLLS` in your client application to get it to pull in the DLL import `__declspec` stuff properly.

See https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=308#c9 for details.

Comment: Had I known this, I could save 10 hours in the past week.